# Set y-axis labels to boxes with facet_wrap and ggarrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, axis-labels, yaxis

Hi there I'm quite new to R and manage to get a plot using both `ggplot` and `ggarrange`; however, I would like to have it more aesthetically pleasing adding the labels for the y-axis (here HG002, HG005 and peru60) within boxes, similarly to what I have for classes of genetic markers (*see* SNPs and INDELs). Below the code and a screenshot of the plot:

```
library(readxl)
library(scales)
library(ggdark)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(reshape2)
library(ggchicklet) #round column
library(RColorBrewer)

excel_HG002 <- read_excel("/media/mat/Extreme SSD/TheUniversityOfFerrara/2°Year/HG002-05_by_site_variants_R.xlsx") # compare variants call (SNVs and INDELs) in HG002
excel_HG005 <- read_excel("/media/mat/Extreme SSD/TheUniversityOfFerrara/2°Year/HG002-05_by_site_variants_R.xlsx", 2) # compare variants call (SNVs and INDELs) in HG002
excel_peru60 <- read_excel("/media/mat/Extreme SSD/TheUniversityOfFerrara/2°Year/HG002-05_by_site_variants_R.xlsx", 3) # compare variants call (SNVs and INDELs) in peru60

dfHG002 <- data.frame(excel_HG002) # for comparing samples genotype (HG002)
dfHG005 <- data.frame(excel_HG005) # for comparing samples genotype (HG005)
dfperu60 <- data.frame(excel_peru60) # for comparing samples genotype (peru60)

dfHG002$variant_type <- factor(dfHG002$variant_type, levels=c('SNPs', 'INDELs')) # order of variant types (HG002)
dfHG005$variant_type <- factor(dfHG005$variant_type, levels=c('SNPs', 'INDELs')) # order of variant types (HG005)
dfperu60$variant_type <- factor(dfperu60$variant_type, levels=c('SNPs', 'INDELs')) # order of variant types (peru60)

df2_HG002 <- with(dfHG002, dfHG002[order(variant_type, assembly, site_type),]) # collapse variants (HG002)
df2_HG005 <- with(dfHG005, dfHG005[order(variant_type, assembly, site_type),]) # collapse variants (HG005)
df2_peru60 <- with(dfperu60, dfperu60[order(variant_type, assembly, site_type),]) # collapse variants (peru60)

### PLOT variants call for HG002-05&peru60 on both assemblies
assessmentHG002 <- ggplot(dfHG002, aes(x=variant_type, y=value, fill=assembly)) + geom_col(position='stack', width=.2, alpha=.6, color='black')
ggplot(df2_HG002, aes(x=site_type, y=value, fill=assembly)) + geom_col(position='dodge', width=.2, alpha=.6, color='black') + 
  facet_wrap(~variant_type, scales='free', nrow=1) + scale_fill_manual(values=rev(brewer.pal(12, "Paired")[c(1:2)])) + labs(x=NULL, y='HG002') +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title='assembly', title.position='top', title.hjust=.5, title.theme=element_text(face='italic'))) +
  theme_bw() + theme(strip.background=element_rect(fill='cornflowerblue')) -> test
  
assessmentHG005 <- ggplot(dfHG005, aes(x=variant_type, y=value, fill=assembly)) + geom_col(position='stack', width=.2, alpha=.6, color='black')
ggplot(df2_HG005, aes(x=site_type, y=value, fill=assembly)) + geom_col(position='dodge', width=.2, alpha=.6, color='black') + 
  facet_wrap(~variant_type, scales='free', nrow=1) + scale_fill_manual(values=rev(brewer.pal(12, "Paired")[c(5:6)])) + labs(x=NULL, y='HG005') +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title='assembly', title.position='top', title.hjust=.5, title.theme=element_text(face='italic'))) +
  theme_bw() + theme(strip.background=element_rect(fill='lightcoral')) -> test2

assessmentPERU60 <- ggplot(dfperu60, aes(x=variant_type, y=value, fill=assembly)) + geom_col(position='stack', width=.2, alpha=.6, color='black')
ggplot(df2_peru60, aes(x=site_type, y=value, fill=assembly)) + geom_col(position='dodge', width=.2, alpha=.6, color='black') + 
  facet_wrap(~variant_type, scales='free', nrow=1) + scale_fill_manual(values=rev(brewer.pal(12, "Paired")[c(9:10)])) + labs(x=NULL, y='peru60') +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title='assembly', title.position='top', title.hjust=.5, title.theme=element_text(face='italic'))) +
  theme_bw() + theme(strip.background=element_rect(fill='violet')) -> test3
  
figure <- ggarrange(test, test2, test3, nrow=3, common.legend=TRUE, legend='bottom')
figure + 
  theme(plot.title=element_text(face='bold.italic', hjust=.5)) + ggtitle("variant_calling — effect of assembly and sample's background")
```

[image: example output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### SOLVED

I actually found a simple function to do the job, below an example

```
### Personalized stripes
ridiculous_strips <- strip_themed(
  ## Horizontal strips
  background_x = elem_list_rect(fill=c("darkolivegreen3", "darkolivegreen4")),
  text_x = elem_list_text(colour=c("black", "black"), face=c("bold", "bold")),
  by_layer_x = FALSE,
  
  ## Vertical strips
  background_y = elem_list_rect(fill = c("cornflowerblue", "lightcoral", "plum")),
  by_layer_y = FALSE
)
```

This is then placed within the `ggh4x::facet_grid2` section usinf the *strip* method. Below the resulting plot:
[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with `facet_grid` I realized it was the only option to do so. I now have a new version for the plot as well as a much more concise code. The only thing I cannot figure out is how to change the color for the second facet on the y-axis; I would like to set blue, red and violet for my three samples.
See below for code and plot:

```
assessmentALL <- ggplot(df2_all, aes(x=variant_type, y=value, fill=assembly)) + geom_col(position='dodge', width=.2, alpha=.6, color='black')
ggplot(df2_all, aes(x=site_type, y=value, fill=assembly)) + geom_col(position='dodge', width=.2, alpha=.6, color='black') + 
  ggh4x::facet_grid2(sample ~ variant_type, scales='free', switch='y', independent='y') + scale_fill_manual(values=rev(brewer.pal(11, "RdBu")[c(1, 11)])) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title='assembly', title.position='top', title.hjust=.5, title.theme=element_text(face='italic', ))) +
  theme_bw() + theme(strip.background=element_rect(fill=c('grey50')), legend.position='bottom') -> testALL
testALL
```

[image: second plot]